# Upgrading AlamoFireImage - Downloading Image

Tags: ios, swift, imagedownload, alamofireimage

How would I upgrade this:

```
ImageDownloader().downloadImage(URLRequest: URLRequest) { response in
  ...
}
```

to the latest `AlamofireImage`? `downloadImage(URLRequest:)` doesn't appear to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`downloadImage(URLRequest:)` has been renamed to `download(_:)`. Check out [AlamofireImage on Github](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) for more information.

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader()

downloader.download(urlRequest) { response in
  ...
}
```